# String map works with literals but not with variables

Tags: tcl

This is the script that I'm running

```
set input_file [ open $ORIGINAL_TESTS_FILE r ];
set output_file  [ open $TESTS_FILE w ];    

set CLASS_NAME "RandTest";
set NEW_CLASS_NAME "JuanDeLosPalotes";

while { [gets $input_file line] >= 0 } {
   #echo $line
   # Replacing string
   set line [ string map { "RandTest" "JuanDeLosPalotes" } $line ];
   #echo $line
   puts $output_file $line
}
close $input_file
close $output_file
```

This reads a text file and replaces RandTest with JuanDeLosPalotes whereever it finds it.

However, if I replace this line

```
set line [ string map { "RandTest" "JuanDeLosPalotes" } $line ];
```

With this line

```
set line [ string map { $CLASS_NAME $NEW_CLASS_NAME } $line ];
```

It does not work (line remains unaltered).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tcl substitution , try `set line [ string map { $CLASS_NAME $NEW_CLASS_NAME } $line ]` by `set line [ string map [list $CLASS_NAME $NEW_CLASS_NAME] $line ]`

Comment: I've just addede the answer I found!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!!!

Curly braces prevent substitution. So I needed to use quotes.

```
set line [ string map "$CLASS_NAME $NEW_CLASS_NAME" $line ];
```

I case anyone needs it.

Comment: Better to use `[list $CLASS_NAME $NEW_CLASS_NAME]`.

Comment: Ok. But why is it preferrable to what  I used?